# How should i handle migrations with 2 apps and 1 database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In our project we have 2 distinct apps (3 if you think about the resque workers), that they use different users for the same database in a remote db server.

The idea is one app `writes stuff on db` and the other `reads stuff from db`. They both have the same models with same attributes, but for security reasons one app cannot in any circumstance write on db.

Because of this setup i have some questions:

1. How can i ensure that both apps in development have the same migrations? should i run migrations on one and copy the code?
2. If i change something on one model, what is the best way to sync the changes?
3. How should i handle capistrano migrating the database? should i just ignore it? or should i create some logic to stop the servers behind that migration?

**EDIT**

I've done some research and found some solutions that i still don't feel confident using.

1. Creating a gem to hold model data

   1. Too messy to handle
   2. For one small change i need to do many things just to update the gem
2. Use `git submodule` or `git subtree`

   1. Not really straightforward
   2. nice to handle shared models but I've no idea what to do with migrations

**EDIT 2**

I have this config for each app:

```
# worker and admin, where i need to write
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: my_huge_db_production
  pool: 5
  username: full_access_user
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# api, where i only need to read
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: my_huge_db_production
  pool: 5
  username: only_read_access_user
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

my biggest problem is how do i sync all changes on my models AND migrations so when i deploy i can say: only call migrations on admin app

Comment: It is safe to say that although they share the same code, they don't share the same remote repository? (git,svn)

Comment: yes, each has its own repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sinatra app is just to expose an api, so it shouldn't be telling you the business rules of your models and tables.

The resque app is just to handle heavy i/o, long requests and stuffs. It shouldnt be telling you nothinng as well.

The rails app is your most important app, because it should handle all your business logic, the user interface (html/css/javascript). It will tell you how your api should be, since your api is based on models defined on it. I think thats the one to handle the migrations.

If you go deeper, you will see that the rails app is the center point of your system. =)

Comment: I agree, but what about model validations? And migrations to work on development?

Comment: As you have replicated you logic through 3 apps, now you will have to mantain the valitions on all of them. Thats a downside of split it this way.

Comment: To work in development, you have 2 options. Stub everything of just run the 3 apps at once. =s
I would recommend the second if possible, since you can check it for real and avoid the trouble of stubing. =)

Answer (score 0):

best way for this is to move your database to Master Slave setup. 
You will run migrations as you run for a single db. it will automatically reflect in other. 
you will be reading from the Slave db and Writing on the Master one.

Comment: i have only one DB, all my apps will connect on the same DB and they will read the same model (e.g. User), my problem is the migrations, how do i make sure all apps have the same DB (especially on development)

Comment: I had similar scenario of yours. What I did was, created master slave setup for my database. One backend app that was doing search (heavy search which results in locks as well) use the slave db only. this is to make sure it don't write anything and at the same time gets the latest of the db. The other app, which actually is the front end of the app and does a lot of writes operations was connected to Master and hence both works smoothly. 
Migrations: Run on master. Just like you run it on a single rails app

Comment: I am checking the git - SubModule to understand your problem better. will update here asap